# Can I use  the PHP DOTNET function?

Tags: apache2, php

I'm a .NET developer and usually I wrote apps/services that can run under Linux using Mono.
Today I started using DOTNET php function and I was able to use it on Windows/Apache:

```
<?php
try{
    $csclass = new DOTNET("CSharpCOM, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, ".
                          "PublicKeyToken=beb607ae770f5750",
                          "CSharpCOM.CSharpCOMClass");
    echo $csclass->Base64("Io mi chiamo Marco Giacinti"),"\n";
    echo $csclass->Random2(10,20),"\n";
    echo $csclass->Random1(5),"\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

where `CSharpCOM.CSharpCOMClass` is a DLL developed with Framework 3.5 and installed in GAC using `gacutil -i path\CSharpCOMClass.dll`.
When I save this script as `dotnet.php` and navigate to `http://localhost/dotnet.php` Apache respond with

```
HTTP 500 internal error
```

Is there any way to use DOTNET php function on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`DOTNET()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php) are in the "Windows Only Extensions" section. I'm guessing that the other PHP binaries don't even have this function compiled.